# How can i integrate chat feature in my Angular4 application?

Tags: angular, chat, angular2-routing, angular4-forms

I want to integrate chatting feature in Angular4 application with text message, smilies, attachment sharing, group chat etc.

Chatting between the users of my application. Users list is available from my database. Want to do chat among them.

Is there any open source frameworks for this?

Please assist

Comment: if your backend is node.js check [socket.io](https://socket.io/) if its asp.net check [signalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Will this support text message, smilies, attachment sharing, group chat etc.?

Comment: please search a mean stack real time chat application...using a node js as a back end is most recommended way for real time applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by Integrating Web Sockets, Node & Angular

> WebSockets is a protocol that provides a bi-directional communication channel. This means that a browser and web server can maintain real-time comms, sending messages back and forth while the connection is open.

here's a full article (tutorial) about how you can create a realtime chat application using node, socket and angular with a working demo: https://medium.com/dailyjs/real-time-apps-with-typescript-integrating-web-sockets-node-angular-e2b57cbd1ec1

of course you can customize the chat by adding icons and attach files ...